# Spring authentication login failure doesn't forward to controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring security to handle login and login error. I have set the failure Url for login. However, when I give it a bad credential, the request seems not to be handled by the controller. I try to set break point on the controller method that handle the failuer authentication but it doesn't jump to that method at all. I don't have a login?error html. I only have a login.html Does anyone know why?

Here is my configure file.

```
 @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/profile").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**","/", "/home", "/signUp").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/homeSignedIn")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(3600).key("mykey")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/signOut")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
}
```

Here is My Controller.

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginPage(Model model){
    Login login = new Login();
    model.addAttribute("login", login);
        return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/homeSignedIn")
public String loggedInPage(){
    return "homeSignedIn";
}


@GetMapping("/signOut")
public String signOutPage(){
    return "signOut";
}

@RequestMapping("/login?error")
public String loginError(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
    return "login";
}
```

}

Here is my login.html.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>

    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p th:if="${loginError}" > Wrong Username or password </p>
<form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <p align="middle">username: <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"></p>
    <p align="middle">password: <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"></p>
    <p align="middle"><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
@RequestMapping("/login?error")
public String loginError(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
    return "login";
}
```

Modify this

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginPage(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) Boolean error){
    if (error == null) {
        Login login = new Login();
        model.addAttribute("login", login);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
    }
    return "login";
}
```

And change configuration to following

```
.failureUrl("/login?error=true")
```

Comment: The request to "http://localhost:8080/login?error=true" still throws me to the error page. Is there something wrong in my login.html?

Comment: I just figured out. I need to do model.addAttribute("login", login) not just when error == null. Thanks. Can you point me out that why my original approach failed?